# Load .qlr file shows up as group, not layer (works on one machine, not another)

Tags: qgis, qlr

I have a project with a few virtual layers that I've saved as **.qlr files** so to be reused in other projects.

When I reload layer from definition file or drag in by browser, everything works as expected; when another user loads the same files on her machine, about half of them come in as a group, not as a layer.

There's no properties or anything available to work with the VL.  We've had to recreate them manually on her machine.